# Counting interpretation of $\sum^{n}_{i=0}\binom{n}{i}i^n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum^{n}_{i=0}\binom{n}{i}i^n$$

I can't find a counting interpretation of this formula. I thought of using the binomial theorem but I don't think it applies here. So, I am not sure how to begin.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A072034

Comment: @metamorphy I still don't understand.

Comment: I got a very bad upper bound, something like $O(n^{n^2})$

Answer (score 4):

I will provide a proof of the interpretation that the sum you've given counts the number of functions from $[n]$ to a subset of $[n]$ summed over all possible subsets(mentioned by @metamorphy) and also $[n] = \{1,2,...,n\}$.Consider a function $$ f : [n] \to [i] $$ Each element of $[n]$ has $i$ choices to map to. So there are $i^n$ functions in this case. Also there are $\dbinom{n}{i}$ subsets of $[n]$ of cardinality $i$ from the definition of binomial coefficients. Summing over all possible subsets you get    that the number of functions  from $[n]$ into a subset of $[n]$ is
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}  \binom{n}{i}i^n$$

Comment: hi, why is $n^i$?

Comment: This is correct, but still I cannot find a good application for it. Any idea or situation where this sum could be useful?

Comment: @Strange is not supposed to be $i^n$ instead of $n^i$?

Comment: If $A\subseteq B\subseteq[n]$, every function from $[n]$ to $A$ is automatically a function from $[n]$ to $B$, so the sum does not count functions from $[n]$ to subsets of $[n]$: it counts ordered pairs $\langle A,f\rangle$ such that $A\subseteq[n]$ and $f:A\to[n]$.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience ,corrected it

Comment: @Strange Can you give a real life example for this to make it more clear?